# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error / GET Request turns from black to red in Firebug

Tags: php, apache, firebug

Is there a general explanation for the errors that lead to the phenomenon described in the title? Can I make the program tell me the actual cause of these errors?

Comment: Yes, you need to look at your error log.

Comment: The problem is occurring on the server so you need to look there.

Comment: FYI: Any HTTP status code of 400 or more is considered an error, so firebug will probably color all of these red.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using PHP backend, HTTP status 500 would mean internal server error - a bug that caused your PHP script to halt. Usually fatal errors cause this.

When you get a 500 error, click on the request in firebug. It would open up all kinds of request data like Headers, Response, Cache, Params etc. Check the response tab once. That might give you a clue about what's wrong in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP status code of 500 means the error happened on the server side. Firebug only sees what's happening on the client side - i.e. it tells you that the server returned an error code. It doesn't have access to the errors happening on the server side.

I.e. you need to check the log files of your server to see what caused the error. This is normally a fatal error in your server-side script that caused its execution to stop.